# How can i execute a jar file?

Tags: jar

to execute a jar file, at the first i installed  openjdk pakeges and then  next command:

java -jar ccnChat.jar

I got this error:
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from ccnChat.jar

then i tried another way:
i right clicked on the jar file, and i marked allow executing file as program from  permissions tab and i chose openjdk as  its default program. then i double clicked on jar file but it didn't open. And there is not any message or error. Could u please help me that how can i execute this jar file?

Answer (score 0):

"Failed to load Main-Class manifest" => This is not a problem with you JDK but only with your MANIFEST.MF file. Have you specified a main-class? Your manifest file should be like this :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass
```

Then you could try to execute again :

```
java -jar ccnChat.jar
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following command:
java -jar file.jar

The answer needs to haveat least thirty words,
so here is some more text, just ignore it